# ClassCastException: javax.naming.Reference cannot be cast to javax.jms.ConnectionFactory when configuring IBM MQ as Flume JMS Source

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, flume-ng

I am trying to configure a Flume (1.6 from Cloudera CDH-5.11.0) agent to use an IBM  WebSphere MQ 9.1.1.0 as Source.

As there's no official documentation, I followed these resources (despite they comes from older versions):

- http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2015/08/configure-flume-to-use-ibm-mq-as-jms.html
- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Ingestion-Integration/Trying-to-integrate-ibm-mq-as-a-flume-source/td-p/5279

I proceeded this way:

1. Installed MQ 9.1.1.0 client and configured the JMSAdmin.conf

   - `INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory
     PROVIDER_URL=file:/C:/temp/jmsbindings
     SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION=none`
2. Created the .bindings file:

   - DEF CF(flumeConnectionFactory) QMGR(myQueueManager) HOSTNAME(myHostName) PORT(1414) CHANNEL(myChannelName) TRANSPORT(CLIENT)
3. Extracted the java client (it is both available as groups of jars from the Windows client or as a single uberjar from IBM Support Portal). I tried both paths, however, right now I extracted these single jars:

   - com.ibm.mq.jar
   - com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
   - com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
   - com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
   - com.ibm.mq.mqjms.jar
   - fcontext.jar
   - jms.jar
   - providerutil.jar
4. Loaded jars and .bindings file on my flume host
5. Prepared this source configuration:

> test_IBM_MQ.sources.amq_ibm.type = jms
>   test_IBM_MQ.sources.amq_ibm.initialContextFactory = com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory
>   test_IBM_MQ.sources.amq_ibm.connectionFactory=flumeConnectionFactory
>   test_IBM_MQ.sources.amq_ibm.providerURL = file:///etc/flume/conf
>   test_IBM_MQ.sources.amq_ibm.destinationName = myDestination
>   test_IBM_MQ.sources.amq_ibm.destinationType = QUEUE

When I finally start my Flume agent, I get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.naming.Reference cannot be cast to javax.jms.ConnectionFactory

Followed by this little Stacktrace

> Source amq_ibm has been removed due to an error during configuration
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.naming.Reference cannot be cast to javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
>       at org.apache.flume.source.jms.JMSSource.doConfigure(JMSSource.java:231)
>       at org.apache.flume.source.BasicSourceSemantics.configure(BasicSourceSemantics.java:65)
>       at org.apache.flume.source.AbstractPollableSource.configure(AbstractPollableSource.java:65)
>       at org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
>       at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:326)
>       at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:101)
>       at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:141)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Inspecting the Flume source, the exploding line is the following

```
connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup(connectionFactoryName);
```

I tried to follow this old related question

- [ClassCastException: javax.naming.Reference cannot be cast to javax.jms.ConnectionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826088/classcastexception-javax-naming-reference-cannot-be-cast-to-javax-jms-connectio)

However, some of the jars the suggest to load do not exist anymore, since the upgrade to jms2.0 from IBM mq v8:

- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q115920_.htm

I am starting to suspect that's there is something which Flume 1.6 which doesn't like JMS2.0

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but:

```
test_IBM_MQ.sources.amq_ibm.connectionFactory=flumeConnectionFactory
```

I believe that parameter is expecting a QueueConnectionFactory (QCF).

Delete the "CF" and add a QCF to your MQ JDNI:

```
DEF QCF(flumeConnectionFactory) QMGR(myQueueManager) HOSTNAME(myHostName) PORT(1414) CHANNEL(myChannelName) TRANSPORT(CLIENT)
```

Also, is this location where the MQ JNDI (".bindings") file is?

```
test_IBM_MQ.sources.amq_ibm.providerURL = file:///etc/flume/conf
```

Based on your above mentioned "PROVIDER_URL" parameter, I think it should be:

```
test_IBM_MQ.sources.amq_ibm.providerURL = file:/C:/temp/jmsbindings
```

Comment: Hello Roger, thanks for the tips. 
I'll try the QCF instead of CF in the connection factory definition. 
As per the other suggestion, I have to add further details to the question, because the client which I used to generate the bindings file is on a Windows PC, but the Flume agend is on a CentOS server. Thanks again!